# Use jQuery to get facebook graph search results as a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get get [Nearby Places](https://www.facebook.com/nearby?query_path=/search/109423102416464/places-near) using jQuery. But I looked in to all the docs in FB but I cannot get it to work. Does anyone know a work around this please ?

So what I need is a JSON object returned for my query.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It means I do not know how to make it work ?! Is that a fair comment ?

Comment: So do you know how to get this [link](https://www.facebook.com/nearby?query_path=/search/109423102416464/places-near) data as a JSON object ?